# Matrix Multiplication wrong in opencv?

Tags: opencv

I know that there are 3 ways to multiply matrices in opencv, one is:

```
cvGEMM(M1, M1T, 1, NULL, 0, Mult, 0);
```

the other:

```
cvMulTransposed(M1, Mult, 0);
```

and third:

```
cvMul(M1, M1T, Mult);
```

I am basically multiplying a matrix by its transpose. After multiplication the matrices should be symmetrical.. but each of the methods above is giving me an unsymmetrical and completely wrong output.. here is the original (M1) matrix:

```
rows: 5
   cols: 50
   dt: f
   data: [ 60., 89., 86., 102., 58., 51., 143., 187., 140., 64., 80.,
       169., 184., 172., 67., 90., 174., 191., 175., 41., 97., 86., 171.,
       104., 87., 145., 164., 176., 157., 119., 176., 177., 180., 179.,
       150., 44., 182., 148., 182., 38., 48., 197., 171., 171., 39., 48.,
       169., 163., 141., 39., 93., 149., 169., 184., 56., 120., 166.,
       182., 168., 144., 132., 172., 187., 173., 157., 164., 157., 152.,
       166., 172., 175., 157., 133., 170., 140., 180., 164., 173., 175.,
       152., 178., 176., 166., 143., 158., 177., 186., 172., 138., 141.,
       182., 191., 169., 159., 34., 185., 154., 155., 171., 32., 81.,
       154., 163., 112., 52., 126., 163., 183., 165., 53., 136., 176.,
       184., 174., 51., 148., 173., 178., 139., 160., 158., 147., 163.,
       154., 135., 146., 157., 181., 161., 79., 39., 172., 187., 174.,
       45., 44., 187., 153., 173., 39., 46., 187., 145., 160., 36., 38.,
       177., 155., 150., 37., 81., 154., 163., 112., 52., 126., 163.,
       183., 165., 53., 136., 176., 184., 174., 51., 148., 173., 178.,
       139., 160., 158., 147., 163., 154., 135., 146., 157., 181., 161.,
       79., 39., 172., 187., 174., 45., 44., 187., 153., 173., 39., 46.,
       187., 145., 160., 36., 38., 177., 155., 150., 37., 76., 165.,
       195., 110., 100., 131., 180., 188., 184., 73., 146., 179., 193.,
       183., 96., 117., 148., 146., 185., 97., 104., 147., 157., 174.,
       172., 129., 171., 177., 181., 173., 123., 126., 186., 194., 171.,
       91., 74., 109., 194., 145., 33., 117., 166., 180., 176., 35., 77.,
       155., 152., 177. ]
```

but multiplying this by its transpose gives this:

```
rows: 5
   cols: 5
   dt: f
   data: [ 927321., 1014163., 923303., 923303., 947641., 1014163.,
       1260101., 1062130., 1062130., 1102823., 923303., 1062130.,
       1004488., 1004488., 990651., 923303., 1062130., 1004488.,
       1004488., 990651., 947641., 1102823., 990651., 990651., 1116004. ]
```

the values are unsymmetrical, also how they got so large is what I dont understand?

cvMultransposed and cvGEMM are giving the same result as copied above.. cvMul is giving some runtime error and returning garbage values. any suggestions?

Comment: Most of the time that I find a "wrong" result, it's because I didn't understand the API or what the correct answer would look like.  A bug in publicly available software is less likely.  A large user base almost guarantees that someone else would have spotted the bug before I did and gotten it fixed.  I'm almost certain that the problem lies with you, your understanding, and your code.

Comment: im not saying that its a bug, and im sure its a mistake by me, but ive been working on it all day and couldnt fix it, that is why I asked for help and suggestions here.

Comment: @Faraz Khan: You should post some code that generates this unexpected behaviour so we can understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the expected large output values (that japreiss already told you about), the matrix that you get IS symmetrical.

I've aligned it for better readability:

```
reshape(a,5,5)

ans =

      927321     1014163      923303      923303      947641
     1014163     1260101     1062130     1062130     1102823
      923303     1062130     1004488     1004488      990651
      923303     1062130     1004488     1004488      990651
      947641     1102823      990651      990651     1116004
```

So, there is nothing wrong here, and you should double-check that X is indeed the case if you go and ask why X occurs in future ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out.. I think im looking at the problem the wrong way.. I'm working on normalizing the values.. maybe that would fix my issues. Also can you please tell me how you re-alligned the matrix? I thought reshape could only work in this format: `cvReshape(mat, &row_header, 0, 1);`.. and did you display the matrix in compiler? I thought it could only be done when we use cvSave when we want to view contents of a matrix

Comment: the reshape was purely for display purposes in matlab (not opencv) as i've entered the numbers as a single line. I just took your matrix output (your second line) and aligned it right.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the lack of symmetry, but the magnitude of the numbers is what I'd expect.  When you're multiplying matrices you take inner products of a row from the first with a column from the second.  Since your rows are 50 elements and your elements are in the 50-200 range, that's going to be around 50*100*100 = 500000 for an element in the output matrix.

Comment: interesting.. thanks for pointing that out.. Ill try rearranging it the other way